# Firedac TFDquery.RowsAffected - returns 1 when should return 0

Tags: delphi, firedac

I have a table 'EMAIL' with unique field 'addr'. When I make a query from mysql console (via Putty) it returns '**0 rows affected**' (since the 'id' didnt actually change), but FIREDAC always returns **rowsAffected=1** (or 2 or 3 if there are more fields). Why is it so, how do I fix that?

```
+----+-------+------+------+
| id | owner | addr | pass |
+----+-------+------+------+
|  1 |  NULL | test | NULL |
+----+-------+------+------+
mysql> update EMAIL set id=last_insert_id(id);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)                        // 0 affected!
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

FIREDAC (FDconnection + FDquery)

```
procedure test;
var conn:TFDCONNECTION;
    query:TFDQUERY;
begin;

conn:=TFDCONNECTION.Create(nil);
query:=TFDQUERY.Create(nil);
query.Connection:=conn;

conn.Params.Add('DriverID=MySQL');
conn.Params.Add('CharacterSet=utf8');
conn.Params.Add('Server=192.168.56.11'); //ubuntu server, v 14.14 5.7.30
conn.Params.Add('User_Name=root');
conn.Params.Add('Password=mypass');
conn.Params.Add('Database=MYDB');
conn.Params.Add('Port=3306');

query.SQL.Text:='update EMAIL set id=last_insert_id(id)';
query.ExecSQL;

//never shows '0', always thinks all the rows have been updated!
showmessage(inttostr( query.RowsAffected ));

query.Close;

conn.Free;
query.Free;
end;
```

[SOLVED!] I edited the source code of 'FireDAC.Phys.MySQL', line 471, commented out the 'CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS' flag (thanks to @Olivier)

Comment: This q needs a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to be added, because FireDAC.Comp.Client.Pas contains no fewer than 22 assignments to RowsAffected and readers need to know which one is involved in this.

Comment: @MartynA thanks for the answer, added a simple example

Comment: Why you think _it should_ returns 0? Your query either insert or update 1 row, thus it returns 1.

Comment: @Sami In fact the behavior depends on the `CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS` flag (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398301/any-way-to-distinguish-the-cases-of-0-affected-row-of-mysql-update)).

Comment: @Sami because when I do this query from console (Putty) it returns '1' then '0'. Firedac always returns '1'

Comment: If FireDAC enables `CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS`, it does explain the observed behavior.

Comment: @Olivier could you please tell where exactly should I check or change this flag (CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS) in Firedac? I'll try then and reply

Comment: The flag is passed as the last parameter of [`mysql_real_connect()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-real-connect.html). You could check in the source of FireDAC how the call is done.

Comment: @Olivier didnt find it so far, will dig deeper today. BUT. I've checked the FIREDAC behavior on simple update (like "UPDATE EMAIL SET addr='yes' WHERE addr!='yes';") and it returned '1' (there was only one record in my table), then '0' (when there was no more matches, everything already was 'yes'). So, basically, it works well with simple updates. But wrong with the tricky one from my question.  Does this mean there's nothing wrong with CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS flag, and the problem is that FIREDAC actually counts the affected rows with it own logic, overwriting the real values? o_O

Comment: UPDATED THE QUESTION, now it looks more simple, the problem persists

Comment: @Olivier I found file "FireDAC.Phyc.MySQL.pas" and commented at line#471 "uiClientFlag := {CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS or} CLIENT_LONG_FLAG;". Now everything works fine! Dude, thanks for your help. If you create an answer to this post, I'll mark at as the right answer

Comment: "Dude, thanks for your help."  I agree, @Olivier often has some fine insights in his comments, people should always take note of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a MySQL database, in the case of `UPDATE` queries, the number of affected rows (returned by [mysql_affected_rows()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-affected-rows.html)) depends on the `CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS` flag.

If the flag is disabled, then only records that are actually modified are taken into account.

If the flag is enabled, then all processed records (whether they are modified or not) are taken into account.

By default, `CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS` is disabled, but FireDAC enables it when it calls [mysql_real_connect()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-real-connect.html).